# a very simple ajax post and print in html with django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I want to enter number in a text box and i want to get all the even numbers. I know this can even be achieved using javascript, but i want to learn ajax with djano. So here is my view

`load_template`

```
@csrf_exempt
def load_template(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':

        num1 =  request.POST['txt1']
        even_num = []

        for n in range(1, int(num1)+1):
             t = n%2
             if t == 0:
                  even_num.append(n)


         return HttpResponse(json.dumps(even_num) , content_type="application/json")

    else :

         return render (request , 'alongjs/index.html')
```

my `index.html`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <body>

    <p> Even numbers </p>

    <!-- <form action="/jsdemo/alongjs/" method="post"> -->

    <form method='post' id ='test'>

         <input type="text" name="txt1"> </input>
         <input type='submit' value='Test button'/>

        <div id = 'message'>Answer: </div>


    </form>


    <script>


        $(document).ready(function() {

            var mes = document.getElementById('message');

           $("#test").submit(function(event){
                $.ajax({

                     type:"POST",
                     url:"/jsdemo/alongjs/",
                     data: {},
                     success: function(data){
                         mes.value = data
                     }
                });
                return false;
           });

        });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I want the answer to come in `Answer :` `div`. but the page is getting refreshed.

and how do i render the page using the format below in html using the above approach:

`in index.html`

```
   {% for num in even_nums %}
        {% num %}
   {% endfor %}
```

I am new to ajax and i know my `ajax post` is not right , please advice.

Comment: Try to insert event.preventDefault(); before ajax call.

Comment: thanks , most of my are working now , how can i populate it as a list using the for loop , after json value is returned.

Comment: Ok, I have posted reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var mes = $('#message');

    $("#test").submit(function(event){

        event.preventDefault(); 

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/jsdemo/alongjs/",
            data: {},
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(i, s){
                    $(mes).append(" " + s);
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```